# Is it possible to set up GStreamer for use in MinGW, similar to how it's done in Linux?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mingw, gstreamer, configure

Apologies for the tardy title, I'm not quite sure how to phrase this question. At its most basic, I'm attempting to compile a program with GStreamer. When running the configure script for said program I get the following error:

```
 0:20.39 configure: checking for gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.0
 0:20.39                       gstreamer-app-1.0
 0:20.39                       gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0
 0:20.39 configure: error: gstreamer and gstreamer-plugins-base development pack
ages are needed to build gstreamer backend. Install them or disable gstreamer su
pport with --disable-gstreamer
```

The build environment I'm compiling in:

- Windows 7 (64-Bit)
- MINGW & MSYS
- Visual C/C++ 2010 SP1 (command line)

Now if this error occurred on a Linux distro, - say Ubuntu - it could be remedied by running the following commands:

```
apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev
```

What is the equivalent for Windows? I've found two type of versions that can be used: The [gstreamer bin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.4.0/gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86_64-1.4.0.msi) from the developer website, which has the following structure:

- bin
- include
- lib
- share

And a [dynamic library of gstreamer for mingw](http://lrn.no-ip.info/other/mingw/mingw32/gstreamer-1.0/1.0.5-1/) with the following structure:

- bin
- lib

How am I supposed to let mingw/msys know that the gstreamer library is installed? Do I place the folders above in the relevant MSYS directories? Then, how does the configure know that it's installed and ready to be used?

I hope what I'm asking makes sense, please let me know if anything is confused. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the first solution (official binaries from GStreamer), you need to tell the configure script where everything is located.

The simplest way is to set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH to where the .pc files are located. Generally it's in

> $install_directory/lib/pkgconfig/

Replace $install_directory with the actual location, ex if it's installed in /c/GStreamer :

> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/c/GStreamer/lib/pkgconfig ./configure

That should make configure figure out everything